# Updating one-to-many relationship using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, eloquent, one-to-many

I am relatively new to Laravel. I am trying to figure out how to use transactions with Eloquent ORM, particularly when it comes to relationships.

Let's say I have one-to-many relationship between two tables: `Recipes` and `Ingredients`, respectively.

One recipe (with its ingredients) looks like:

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Lasagna',
    'readyIn' => '30 minutes',
    'ingredients' => [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'noodles', 'quantity' => '8'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'cheese', 'quantity' => '2 cups']
    ]
]
```

When updating an existing recipe, the request comes to me as:

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Lasagna',
    'readyIn' => '1 hour',
    'ingredients' => [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'noodles', 'quantity' => '9'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'mozarella cheese', 'quantity' => '3 cups'],
        ['id' => null, 'name' => 'sauce', 'quantity' => '1 jar'],
        ['id' => null, 'name' => 'onion', 'quantity' => '1']
    ]
]
```

My approach was to do the following to update a recipe:

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($request, $id) {
    // update existing recipe
    $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
    $recipe->fill($request->all());
    $recipe->save();

    // get old & new ingredients
    $oldIngredients = $recipe->ingredients();
    $newIngredients = $request->get('ingredients');

    // delete old ingredients that do not appear in the new list
    if ($ids = array_diff(
        array_pluck($oldIngredients, 'id'),
        array_pluck($newIngredients, 'id')
    )) {
        Ingredient::destroy($ids);
    }

    // save new ingredients
    foreach ($newIngredients as $attributes) {
        // update existing ingredient
        if ($id = array_pull($attributes, 'id')) {
            $ingredient = Ingredient::find($id);
            $ingredient->fill($attributes);
            $ingredient->save(); 
        // create new ingredient
        } else {
            $recipe->ingredients()->create($attributes);
        }
    }
});
```

From my understanding, using this approach, wouldn't there be a disconnect between those in the `Ingredients` table and the `$recipe`'s ingredients? As in `Ingredient::destroy($ids)` and `$ingredient->save()` only changes the records in the `Ingredients` table, but not `$recipe`'s ingredients. If so, is there a way to update the `$recipe` as I update or delete ingredients? My goal is to have an updated `$recipe` including its ingredients after the transaction completes.

Comment: I feel like this would make more sense as a `many-to-many`, where a Recipe can have many Ingredients, that each can belong to many Recipes. You'd just use a pivot between the two, with an additional Quantity column. It would need a bit of additional logic to handle finding or creating then attaching Ingredients to the Recipe, but using a one-to-many will result in potential duplicate Ingredients, which doesn't seem right (to me anyway)

Comment: You can reload the relationship afterwards: `$recipe->load('ingredients');` Is that what you mean?